# error al firmar apk release

Tags: android, apk

Estoy intentando firmar la apk pero en release me sale un error mientras que en debug me hace bien la apk, lo malo que la playstore la debug me la rechaza

este es el fallo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna idea de por donde puede estar el fallo? y por que me deja firmar en debug y no en release?

Comment: Lujan, ve a Help > Show Log in Explorer y revisa que fue lo último que registro tu proyecto.

Comment: ya se de donde viene el fallo, de una de las imagenes, las borre todas menos una y al final me dejo crear la apk firmada,  ahora tocara encontrar la imagen que es

Comment: es un recurso, era lo que comentaba a Gastón, un simple Rebuild no soluciona este problema. En el Log se debe desplegar más información sobre el problema